# Unable to use sudo and other apps

Tags: sudo, chmod

I've been learning file security on my main OS (Ubuntu 16.04). I changed my /usr directory's permissions by executing `sudo chmod 750 /usr` command. Now, I'm not able to execute any app and not able to use sudo command anymore. I had never back-up the system. Is it possible to recover this?

How can I recover this with live USB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot in recovery-mode. There you are root. `mount -o remount,rw /`

```
chmod 0755 /usr
```

Comment: I'm not able to boot in recovery-mode since I get 'Low-graphics mode' error. When I enter 'Exit to console login' option nothing changed.

Comment: Okay , then boot a Live-Session. Mount the /- Partition from your Ubuntu-Installation and make the change from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the root password, and you don't want to reboot into recovery mode or into a live CD/USB, you can switch to the root account:

```
$ su -
```

And then change the permissions on the `/usr` directory:

```
# chmod o+r /usr
```

Comment: I don't know the root password.